# passing php variables to html with the right format

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, format

I am very new to programming and therefore have some "doubts". One I have not sorted is regarding how to pass data in a certain format from php to html.  on communication.

What I am trying to do is to use this part of program to insert gps locations in Google map.

bit that works: I can export data like a single string from php to html
                I can plot the map as I want if i input the data form html

my understanding is that php array is not compatible in format with teh input required from the html var.. here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Define your locations
    **var locations = [
      ['<h4>One</h4>', -30.2, 100.6],
      ['<h4>Two</h4>', -31.2, 100.7],
      ['<h4>Three</h4>', -32.2, 100.8]
    ];**


    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

    var icons = [
      iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png'
    ]
    var icons_length = icons.length;


    var shadow = {
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
      url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 160
    });

    var marker;
    var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon : icons[iconCounter],
        shadow: shadow
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally I would like to replace the var locations with a variable I already built in php (so far is built in the same page) and then pass it to var locations.

i tried passing the array in the following way:

```
    <?php
$locations = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
$locations[] = ['One',$x,$x+1,$x+2];

}
$loc = $_POST[$locations];
//$loc = $_POST['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>, -33.890542, 151.274856'];
print_r ($locations);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var cars = <?php print_r ($loc); ?>;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but had no luck. Can anyhow support please? 
Many thanks

### -------------------------------------------------------------

Update!!! Thanks to all of you I managed to establish how to pass the variable

```
<?php
$arr = array("Bondi Beach",",-33.890542",",151.274856");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = locations[1];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the next step is to try to pass an array... tried the following but again not working...

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
$arr[] = ["One",$x,$x*2];
};
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var arr = new Array(3);
for (i = 0; i <= 3; $i++) {
arr[i] = <?php echo json_encode($arr[i]) ?>;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[1];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

maybe is a too naive attempt...

---

## **SORTED**

Thanks for all of your support. I wish to see you soon (as members of my website!)

Really thanks :-)
Emanuele

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: @Murplyx is trying to guide to the wonderous world of JSON. A language designed to transmit data between languages and other sources. Both javascript and PHP can encode and decode objects to JSON, making them interchangeable.

Comment: @Murplyx You just commented with a link. That links redirects to a page explaining JSON. It seems that the OP isn't really familiar with JSON. Some explanation may be necessary. I tried to give your comment more context for the OP.

Comment: It's a nice thing to accept an answer that helped you in the right direction.

Comment: @Mouser I would like to vote the best answer but have not the reputation for doing that yet (I need 15 rather than my actual 6), thanks all again

Comment: @EmanueleCacciaglia, but you can accept an answer by clicking the greyed `v` below the vote buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSON**: A language designed to transmit data between languages and other sources. Both *JavaScript* and *PHP* can encode and decode objects to JSON, making them interchangeable. This is the modern and most common way of transferring data. XML is still used, but generates more overhead than JSON.

```
<script>
var cars = <?php json.encode($loc); ?>;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars.join(", ");
</script>
```

The code above will transform the *PHP array object* to *JSON* with `json_encode`. JavaScript parses the `JSON string` to a javascript *array object*. The function `join` is there to let you see the result.

To actually retrieve the values use:

```
cars[0]; //<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>
cars[1]; //-33.890542
cars[2]; //151.274856
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is JavaScript Object Notation and you can use the php function json_encode  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: While this link may provide the answer, it's better to explain the key parts of the answer in your post. Links and contents change.

Comment: It realy needs the JSON.parse function?  U can simply print the javascriptcode with PHP.

Comment: If not it will be just rendered as string and not as an object.

Comment: rendered as a javascript array definition . u print with php the javascriptcode